# Using python requests library on Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, python-requests

How can I use [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) on a spider in Scrapy?

```
import scrapy, requests

def parse(self, response):
    # do things...
    # then

    yield requests.get(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrapy.Request` for this. Use it as follows:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy import Request

def parse(self, response):
    # do things...
    # then

    yield Request(response.url, 
                  callback=self.parse, 
                  dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: I tried with scrapy requests but works different, in same site I have different response